# [kdl_parser tutorial] where is manifest.xml in indigo?

Tags: ros, manifest.xml

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I learn the tutorial about "Start using the KDL parser",and it 's says :
"First, add the KDL parser as a dependency to your manifest.xml (in hydro is package.xml)file:"
I don't know where it is............

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255384/%5Bkdl_parser-tutorial%5D-where-is-manifest.xml-in-indigo?/) by [Ddj](https://answers.ros.org/users/29459/ddj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've updated [the tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/kdl_parser/Tutorials/Start%20using%20the%20KDL%20parser?action=diff&rev2=11&rev1=10) to clarify that in newer ROS distros (after [Groovy](http://wiki.ros.org/groovy)) you're encouraged to use package.xml. You may want to go through the basic http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials especially [this session](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage) where you learn package creation.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0